# Samsung Ace 4 Unable to charge message, but it does still charge

Tags: samsung, battery, charging, samsung-galaxy-ace

I have a problems with my phone. The phone dropped and since then I got an issue with charging it. When I plug in the charging cable I get the following message:

**"Unable to charge. Charging paused. Battery temperature too low."**

The Battery Sign on the screen is blinking, but the percentage will not go up. When I unplug it after lets say an hour it still shows the same, but when I either plug in the cable again or restart the phone, the percentage will suddenly go up. So it shows me that it charged, but it does not show it while it is charging nor when I unplug the cable and it keeps coming with the above Error Message. I assume that the USB port is still fine otherwise it would not charge, but what could be the problem?

Comment: Could be hardware or software. Flashing stock will help decide. If it persists, it is hardware (which I suspect is more likely)

Comment: Thanks for getting back. If you think it's a hardware problem, would it be the battery or the USB port board? I finally got it up to 86% but it seems stuck now on that since 2 hours. so it does seem to charge, but not as I thought all the time instead it seems to stop in between.

Comment: Honestly I can't say. It could be many things- I wouldn't hazard a guess with the information available but let's first rule out other things by flashing stock

Comment: Well the phone is actually from a friend who is in hospital and I am not sure I can flash his phone since then everything will be lost. If it most likley the USb port then I would just order one and if it more likley the battery I would get that, but I just wonder because it does seems to charge partly, but comes with that message all the time and I am still not getting it above 86%

Comment: Like I said , too many possibilities - USB, battery terminals not making contact correctly /broke, battery sending information correctly but OS unable to register because OS issue, all above fine but battery dying, who can say? If you can't flash ROM best is to take to competent service folks. Afraid I can't help beyond , much as I would like to

Comment: Well thank you anyway,. I,might just get the USB Port and see from there.